# How to get MELPA packages documentation

Tags: emacs

I can configure my Emacs and install MELPA packages.I just want to find out how these packages work,so I want to get their documentation. However I can't find any.

I searched in https://melpa.org ,but I can not find them. I want to find out how these packages have been organized and designed.

Comment: I want to find out company-mode for example.

Comment: What do you mean by *document*? The package recipe?

Comment: I want to write my own company-mode to improve my skills.I want to know how the company-mode is been designed.What the data structure It contains.And what these data structure means.I think C language data structure makes me clear.

Comment: As in another question, I think he means documentation. Don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the package's documentation, just start with its readme, on melpa if it's there, or on the project's home page.

The doc doesn't necessarily include design decisions, in which case you'll have to read the source. Either on the internet, or if you installed the package in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I read these documentation,but can't understand well.Do you have another way to learn Emacs lisp well?

Comment: oh, this is another topic ! What resources did you use ? Start with the official manual, read blogs,… http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_idioms.html http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Category:Emacs_Lisp https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/elisp/